# Error running foreman to fire up a Node.js app

Tags: node.js, heroku, foreman

I am trying to run foreman on a Mint VM i just setup. It is for the purpose of learning node. I am using Heroku and their guide to get myself setup but i have hit a road block when i try and start foreman.

The error message is:

```
14:51:09 web.1  | started with pid 10739
14:51:09 web.1  | exited with code 1
14:51:09 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

Comment: The error message suggests that node has not been installed.

Comment: Before I can provide an answer, could you specify the URL of the guide you are following?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#store-your-app-in-git

Comment: I reinstalled node and now i am getting a different error

`14:51:09 web.1  | started with pid 10739
14:51:09 web.1  | exited with code 1
14:51:09 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
`

Comment: Can you update your question with the error you are not getting please.

Comment: Have you run `npm install`?

Comment: yep i have done that for sure

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35789/discussion-between-aaronf8-and-gordyd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are following a guide specifically for use on a Heroku instance then it will skip some steps that will be required for setting up on other boxes. By default heroku instances have `node.js` installed, so there is no need to get this set up on the box prior to deploying and launching your first application.

To install Node.js on Linux Mint. Do the following:

1. Install required tools

   `sudo apt-get install g++ curl libssl-dev apache2-utils`

   `sudo apt-get install git-core`
2. Clone and make latest version of Node.js

   `git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git`

   `cd node`

   `./configure`

   `make`

   `sudo make install`
3. Go to your working directory for this project and run the following:

   `npm install`

   `foreman start`

Your Node.js application example should now be working on your local VM.

To get a sample node app for testing your local setup do the following:

```
`git clone git@github.com:heroku/node-js-sample.git # or clone your own fork`

`cd node-js-sample`

`npm install`

`foreman start`
```

Browse to `http://localhost:5000` to see the sample application.

Comment: I just followed exactly this with the files stated in the guide and i am getting the error message above

Comment: Did you ever solve this? 1.5 years later still the same problem

Comment: I just ran into the same issue on Windows 8.1. The solution turned out to be that index.js and package.json need to be overwritten with the exact contents stated in the tutorial. I had extra unneeded content in my files that made it different than those in the tutorial at the step where it failed.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while but since none of the above answers worked for me I thought I'd post what I did to get Heroku foreman to work with Express 4 (took me ages to figure out!)

In your app.js (or whatever your entry file is):

**Add this line the app.use(express.static(path.join....**

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
```

**Add this line to the end of your file:**

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
});
```

**If you were using the express-generator, remove this line:**

```
module.exports = app;
```